# Как вытащить с базы все строки средствами php и добавить в js код?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Друзья подскажите как вытащить из базы все строки по критерию, и добавить в JS код?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test() 
{
    function one() {
        $("#results").html('<img src="url">');
    }
}
</script>
```

Мне нужно циклом добавить такую строку `$("#results").html('<img src="url">');` с url`ом который вытащить с базы.. Не понимаю как это реализовать т.к в JS вообще полный 0.

т.е если в базе 10 строк которые нашли по критерию добавить 10 раз `$("#results").html('<img src="url">');` с параметром который взят со строки которую мы вытащили с базы..

Comment: А что будет делать ваша функция на JS?

Comment: Выводить картинки при вызове ф-и

Comment: Целый день искал решение, пробывал сам, ничего не получилось. Пишу сюда

Comment: $query = "select * from tabl1 where url";
$result = $conn1->query($query);
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$arr2[]=$row2;
}

Comment: создай базу с клонкой url и запроси её

Comment: Как получить что-то с базы на уровне PHP я знаю, я не понимаю как это сделать в JS... Или же как это сделать на PHP с передачей в JS... Дело то вот в чем.

Comment: @Иван зайдите в чат, если вы не справились в итоге.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы получили из БД массив с вашими ссылками, то можно обработать его в цикле, тогда логика будет примерно такова:

Кнопка для примера:

```
<span id="clickBtn" class="someBtn">Button</span>
```

Обработчик нажатия

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#clickBtn").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        <?php 
            foreach($query_result as $key => $row){
                echo '
                    $("#results").append("<img src="'.$row['url_name'].'">");
                ';
            }
        ?>
    });
});
```

Вместо `.html()` , есть еще `.append()`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101664/discussion-on-answer-by-nikolay-gabaraev-------).